# Не проходит один из тестов. Рекурсия, задача "Легион"

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия, олимпиада

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int func(int k, int u) {
    if (k == 3) { u++; return u; }
    else if (k > 3) {
        if (k % 2 == 0) {
            return (func((k / 2), u) * 2);
        }
        else {      
                return (func((k - (k / 2)), u) + func((k / 2), u));
            
        }
        
    }
    else { return u; }
}


int main()
{
    int k = 0, u = 0;
    cin >> k;
    
    cout << func(k, u);;
    return 0;
}
```

Легион – основная организационная единица в армии Древнего Рима. В разное время легионы имели разную численность и различное построение. Самым простым построением была шеренга. Чтобы из N солдат легиона, выстроенных в шеренгу, отобрать троих в разведку, выполнялись следующие операции: если солдат в шеренге больше трех, то шеренга разбивалась на две, одна из которых состоит из солдат, стоящих на четных позициях, а вторая – из стоящих на нечетных позициях. Для всех полученных шеренг эта процедура повторялась до тех пор, пока в каждой из них не останется не более трех солдат. Если солдат осталось трое, то данную группу можно послать в разведку.
Легион
Требуется определить, сколько групп по три человека может быть сформировано из исходной шеренги.
Задача:
https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=923

Я проверила больше 20 тестов, но не могу понять, в чем проблема...

Измененный код:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
   long long int func(long long int k) {
        if (k == 3) { return 1; }
        else if (k > 3) {
            if (k % 2 == 0) {
                return ((func(k / 2)) * 2);
            }
            else {      
                    return (func((k - (k / 2))) + func((k / 2)));
                
            }
            
        }
        else { return 0; }
    }
    
    
    int main()
    {
        long long int k = 0;
        cin >> k;
        
        cout << func(k);;
        return 0;
    }
```

Исправленный конечный вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
long long int func(long long int k, map <long long int, long long int> &m) {
    if (k == 3) { return 1; }
    else if (k > 3) {
        if (m.find(k) != m.end()) { return m[k]; }
        if (k % 2 == 0) {
            long long int kl = ((func((k / 2), m)) * 2);
            m.insert(pair <long long int, long long int>(k, kl));
            return kl;
        }
        else {
            long long int ff = (func((k - (k / 2)), m) + func((k / 2), m)      );
            m.insert(pair <long long int, long long int>(k, ff));
            return ff;
        }

    }
    else { return 0; }
}


int main()
{
    long long int k = 0;
    map <long long int, long long int> m;
    cin >> k;

    cout << func(k, m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я бы сказал, что проблема - в алгоритме (правда, понять, что тут запрограммировано и почему - затруднительно). Но раз регулярно банят - то, вероятно, проблема всё же в голове, которая не хочет учиться, даже на своих ошибках...

Comment: для начала int -> long long. там 10 ^ 18 числа.

Comment: ну и да. зачем вам параметр u в рекурсии непонятно вообще.

Comment: @Akina, алгоритм рабочий и очень быстрый. Наверно, можно всё свернуть в замкнутую формулу, н и так решение хорошее. Вся проблема в переполнениях. Но об этом уже написали.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Охотно верю. Я о том, что формулировка вопроса не выдерживает никакой критики - порой из-за формы подачи могут быть закрыты даже достаточно неплохие вопросы...

Comment: Спасибо, скажите, в чем у меня заключается неправильная формулировка вопроса?

Comment: Кстати, мой код прошел чуть дальше, но застрял из-за wrong answer

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос изменённый код.

Comment: Убрала из кода u, все тот же wrong answer на том же тесте. Эх

Comment: `int func` ??? `int` всё ещё на месте. Вы тестировали?

Comment: тест 7 * 2 ^ 50 скажем. можно больше =)

Comment: А, ой, там забыла. Прошел еще чуть дальше, теперь тайм лимит

Comment: Я добавила мап, и он ПРОШЕЛ!!!!!!!!!!!! УРААААА

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С самого начала  вы взяли правильное направление. Алгоритм был правильный и быстрый. Не хватило (1) правильно выбрать тип для вычислений и хранения результата и (2) кешировать промежуточные результаты. Вы исправили оба недочёта и решили задачу. Сами. Честь и хвала!

Я покажу другое решение ...

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    uint64_t n;
    std::cin >> n;

    uint64_t m = 0;
    if (n >= 3) {
        uint64_t p;
        for (p = 1; p <= n / 2; p *= 2) {
        }
        if (n <= p + p / 2) {
            m = n - p;
        } else {
            m = 2 * p - n;
        }
    }
    std::cout << m << '\n';
}
```

... и расскажу как к нему прийти.

Обозначим ***f<sub>N</sub>*** - искомое число троек.

Таблица значений:

> ```
>  N     f_N   график        N     f_N   график
>  
>  0      0    *            16      0    *
>  1      0    *            17      1     *
>  2      0    *            18      2      *
>  3      1     *           19      3       *
>  4      0    *            20      4        *
>  5      1     *           21      5         *
>  6      2      *          22      6          *
>  7      1     *           23      7           *
>  8      0    *            24      8            *
>  9      1     *           25      7           * 
> 10      2      *          26      6          *
> 11      3       *         27      5         *
> 12      4        *        28      4        *
> 13      3       *         29      3       *
> 14      2      *          30      2      *
> 15      1     *           31      1     *
> 16      0    *            32      0    *
> ```

Наблюдения:

- ***f<sub>2</sub> = 0*** - по определению;
- ***f<sub>2N</sub> = 2f<sub>N</sub>*** - по определению;
- ***f<sub>2<sup>K</sup></sub> = 0*** - следует из предыдущего;
- ***f<sub>2N+1</sub> = f<sub>N</sub> + f<sub>N+1</sub>*** - по определению;

Теперь хитрее:

- ***f<sub>3</sub> = 1*** - по определению;
- ***f<sub>3·2<sup>K</sup></sub> = 2<sup>K</sup>*** - по индукции (***f<sub>2(3·2<sup>K</sup>)</sub> = 2f<sub>3·2<sup>K</sup></sub>***).

Значения ***f<sub>2<sup>K</sup></sub>*** - долины между холмами, ***f<sub>3·2<sup>K</sup></sub>*** - вершины холмов.

Докажем по индукции что если ***2·2<sup>K</sup> ≤ N ≤ 3·2<sup>K</sup>***, то ***f<sub>N</sub> = N - 2·2<sup>K</sup>***. База ***K = 0*** проверяется непосредственно (***2 ≤ N ≤ 3***, ***f<sub>2</sub> = 0***, ***f<sub>3</sub> = 1***).

Индукционный переход: пусть это верно для ***K***, докажем для ***K+1***:

Имеем ***2·2<sup>K+1</sup> ≤ N ≤ 3·2<sup>K+1</sup>***.

Если ***N*** - чётное (***N = 2M***), то ***f<sub>N</sub> = 2f<sub>M</sub>***. Заметим что ***2·2<sup>K</sup> ≤ M ≤ 3·2<sup>K</sup>***. По индукционному предположению ***f<sub>M</sub> = M - 2·2<sup>K</sup>***, тогда ***f<sub>N</sub> = 2M - 2·2·2<sup>K</sup> = N - 2·2<sup>K+1</sup>***.

Если ***N*** - нечётное (***N = 2M + 1***), то ***f<sub>N</sub> = f<sub>M</sub> + f<sub>M+1</sub>***. Заметим что ***2·2<sup>K</sup> ≤ M, M + 1 ≤ 3·2<sup>K</sup>***.  По индукционному предположению ***f<sub>M</sub> = M - 2·2<sup>K</sup>***, ***f<sub>M+1</sub> = M + 1 - 2·2<sup>K</sup>***, тогда ***f<sub>N</sub> = (M - 2·2<sup>K</sup>) + (M + 1 - 2·2<sup>K</sup>) = 2M + 1 - 2·2·2<sup>K</sup> = N - 2·2<sup>K+1</sup>***.

Доказано.

Аналогично доказывается что если ***3·2<sup>K</sup> ≤ N ≤ 4·2<sup>K</sup>***, то ***f<sub>N</sub> = 4·2<sup>K</sup> - N***.

Что приводит нас к программе в начале этого сообщения, которая вычисляет результат в константной памяти и за время ***logN***.